# How to reinstall python env for GM?

Tags: python, installation, dm-script

Recently the conda environment for GMS crashed, so I delete the folder of miniconda3. I wonder how can I reinstall it. Do I need to reinstall GMS?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not really a coding question, but rather a question on setting up the software. While of interest - and answered - it does not really belong here.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you don't need to reinstall GMS completely but I would suggest it.

---

If you want to install Miniconda manually, download the corresponding installer from the [official Miniconda site](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html). Take any miniconda installation with python 3.7.

Install Miniconda in the same directory as before (not necessary, but recommended). For windows this is `%ProgramData%\Miniconda3`.

After installation create a new environment. The default environment coming with GMS is called `GMS_VENV_PYTHON` but you can use any name you want. You can do that by running the command

```
conda create --name GMS_VENV_PYTHON python=3.7.2
```

Note that GMS 3.4 comes with python 3.7.2 but according to the help you can use any python 3.7, there is no problem with "versions that differ by minor version, e.g. 3.7.5 and 3.7.6" (GMS help in *Python* > *Installation and Configuration* > *Configuration*).

After restarting your computer open GMS and go to *File* > *Global Info* and in the *General* tab on the left open *Scripting*. In the bottom you can choose your python version. Select the created environment (`GMS_VENV_PYTHON`).

After restarting GMS python scripting should work again. If not, make sure minicondas python is listed in the `PATH`.

Comment: +1  I second miile7's opinion. While it may not be essential to do this, it might just be the fastest and savest way to get to a clean start and avoiding potential issues. Alternatively, you could run the GMS installer with "modify", just remove Python, and run it again in "modify" to just install it. But as this is virtually the same time and effort as doing a "deinstall" / "reinstall" (make sure to keep licenses and on install use "old preferences"), I would recommend to do the full-cycle instead.